# 504 Deadline Exceeded: BigQuery to Firestore Collection using Python in Batch Writes Mode

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I am working on the setup as mentioned below and getting the error:
"504 Deadline Exceeded"

1. Read approx. 10k rows from BigQuery in Cloud Function using Python
2. Write those 10k rows to a Firestore collection using the below code -
   -- Batch size is selected as 500
   -- It forms smaller batches (approx. 20) and loads the data

```
max_batch_size = 500
for i in range(0, len(records), max_batch_size):
    batch_number += 1
    batch = firestore_client.batch()
    for data in records[i:i+max_batch_size]:
        doc_ref = collection_ref.document()
        batch.set(doc_ref, data)
    try:
        batch.commit()
    except GoogleAPIError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
```

I am consistently facing the "504 Deadline Exceeded" error.

Things that I have already tried -

1. Changing the batch size to 1000, it still fails. Changing to 200, it becomes very slow and sometimes fails as well.
2. Adding index to the Firestore collection (? Not sure about this since adding/removing index would help)

A few questions:

1. Is there any better way to handle this error? I am unable to find any consistent behavior.
2. As I know, the `batch.commit()` timeout is 60s. How can I change it to a bigger value? Also, is this recommended?

Comment: Have you tried increasing timeout as suggested in this [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/11)? Also, check out this [best practices for designing for scale](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#designing_for_scale).

Comment: For the github issue link provided, that is for each document level write and not the batch level. Do you know how to do it for the batch commits? Also, I went through the best practices and tried to implement some of the suggestions. Will post here if the timeout issue is resolved.

Comment: Have you tried using [`python bulk writer`]([https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/blob/main/google/cloud/firestore\_v1/bulk\_writer.py\#L232](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/blob/main/google/cloud/firestore_v1/bulk_writer.py#L232))?